# Rmagick composite image without source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, carrierwave, rmagick, fog

I have a Gallery model and a Post model.  Each Post has an image, and I would like to create a composite image for each Gallery based on the posts in that gallery.  I have a method for galleries that returns urls to the top 4 images in the gallery:

```
gallery.images_for_preview # => returns array of 4 image urls (200x200 images)
```

I'm using Carrierwave + RMagick to generate a composite image. I'm trying to follow along here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/374-image-manipulation but it seems my use case is slightly different. I have:

```
class GalleryImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ...
  def store_dir
    "galleries/#{model.obfuscated_id}"
  end

  version("full") { process :full_image }

  def full_image
    images = model.images_for_preview
    puts images
    manipulate! format: "png" do
      image0 = Magick::Image.read(images[0]).first
      image1 = Magick::Image.read(images[1]).first
      image2 = Magick::Image.read(images[2]).first
      image3 = Magick::Image.read(images[3]).first
      underlay = Magick::Image.new(406, 406) { self.background_color = "#333333" }
      underlay.composite!(image0, 2, 2, Magick::OverCompositeOp).composite!(image1, 204, 2, Magick::OverCompositeOp).composite!(image2, 2, 204, Magick::OverCompositeOp).composite!(image3, 204, 204, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
    end
  end
```

The full_image operation doesn't require a source file, but the only way I can seem to get it to generate the composite image is to do something like:

```
gallery.remote_image_url = "path/to/image"
```

which generates the image I need at `/galleries/:id/full_image.png` but also processes and generates an image at `/galleries/:id/image.png`

Is it possible to skip the "source" image and just generate a composite, then upload that as the ImageUploader's primary image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just process the data on the go, no need for the version itself:

Replace this line:

```
  version("full") { process :full_image }
```

With this one

```
  process :full_image
```